# VBA - Inserting Rows Based on count of adjacent cells with data

Tags: vba, excel, rows, unpivot

Here is my scenario: 
10 Columns from A to J, 
100 rows.  Each row can have any where from 1 to 10 entries.

I need to count the number of cells with data in each row, and insert that same amount of rows beneath the row that was just counted.

EX: Row 1 has entries in Columns A-D, then I'd need 4 rows inserted below row 1. 
EX2:  Row 20 has entries in columns A-G, then i'd need 7 rows inserted below row 20

Any help is greatly apprecaited

Answer (score -1):

This isn't a complete answer, but hopefully it'll push you in the right direction (I'm pretty new to programming myself).

```
Dim RowNum as integer
Dim ColNum as integer
Dim NumRowsToInsert as integer


For RowNum=100 to 1
    NumRowsToInsert=0
    For ColNum=1 to 10
        If cell  has value, then
        NumRowsToInsert=NumRowsToInsert+1
        End if
    Next ColNum    
    insert coding to insert "NumRowsToInsert" rows below row "RowNum" here
Next RowNum
```

This logic should work for you. But you'll need to fix the coding.